# coldfusion administrator 500 error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I installed CF 9 over CF 8 a while ago. CF9 installed in a different drive and the CF8 service is not running.  I had to change the virtual location manually for the two sites that had cfide mapped to point to the new drive letter.  All my websites run great except for the ColdFusion Administration page. Normally I get a 500 error but this morning I'm just getting a blank page.

CF9 standard on IIS.

This is our development server, fortunately our production server is running fine.  From what I can tell both are configured the same way and were installed the same way.  I'm planning on a re-install if I can't get it figured out but would like to avoid that.

What would cause the administrator to crap out when every other site runs fine?

Thanks.

Comment: So...which is it? a 500 error? Or a blank page? Your question title contradicts the last sentence of your first paragraph.

Comment: well, as I said it was throwing 500 errors, as of this morning it was showing a blank page.  I needed time to confirm this in other environments.  The only thing I did yesterday was increase the cf user account's permissions and remap the cfide virtual.

Comment: Now that the behavior has changed I'm getting different search results. I found a good blog post from Charlie I'm going to look over. http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2011/10/21/why_chfs_may_break

Answer (score 1):

It may have something to do with the fact that you moved your CFIDE folder.  The admin assumes its in C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\cfide\administrator.  So you can try to copy that administrator folder and put it in C:\inetpub then open a browser and go to localhost/adminstrator.  Worth a shot.